# Why to call private function from a public one, instead of implemente code in public one?

Tags: go

I see a lot of codes like this in the golang src:

```
func Open(path string) (*Plugin, error) {
    return open(path)
}

func open() {
  // etc
}
```

A private function been called from a public. Why not just:

```
func Open(path string) (*Plugin, error) {
    // code of open here
}
```

ref: https://golang.org/src/plugin/plugin.go?s=1065:1104#L21

I do understand that sometimes it makes sense, especially if there are more functions using `open`. But that's not the case.

Is this some kind of Golang way of organizing things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case, it appears to be because the actual implementation is OS dependent.

The plugin implementation `plugin_dlopen.go` is used only for OSX and Linux, and the alternative `plugin_stubs.go` is for everything else(which just contains dummy functions as there is no implementation for other systems yet.)

This allows you to keep OS dependent code in one file using [build tags](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints), while keeping general code, the public API and documentation for the public API in a single place.